# Error message "Nontype object has no get attribute"

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I retrieved some data using API and tried extracting the country code using this python script but got an error message:

> Nonetype object has no get attribute.

The data is in a JSON file. Here is my code:

```
country_code=[data.get("sys").get("country") for data in weather_data].
```

Comment: Check the response of the api first, what is the data you are getting ?

Comment: what's in weather_data?

Comment: One of the items in `weather.data` is `null`, which is translated into `None` by Python's JSON parser.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. It turned out one of the items in the dataset is null. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you `.get('key-x')` from a dict that does not contain `'key-x'` None will be returned. You can change this behaviour by specifying `.get('key-x', default_return_value)` where `default_return_value` is a variable whose value you would like to return from the invocation given that the key does not exist. In this case you are chaining two `.get` calls where the first  `.get`call seems to be retuning None and this type, unlike a dictionary, does not have a `.get` function. I would start debugging this by printing out the content of the `data` variable here and seeing if the `'sys'` key actually exists in it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You are right. It turned out one city was not found, so the city's data was missing. Again i appreciate your help.

Comment: @DeshanYu np -- happy it helped